# Ожидание завершения всех Ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

С помощью Ajax формирую массив:

```
(function(elem, datename, date, j) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {                                          
            date[datename][j] = data;                   
        }
    }
});
```

На выходе:

[image: результат]

Но при

```
var newarray = [];
var i = 0;
for (var elem in date) {
    newarray[i++] = [date[elem][0], date[elem][1]]; 
}
console.log(newarray);
```

получаю `[[undefined, undefined], [undefined, undefined]]`.

Такое ощущение, что данные из Ajax запроса еще не загрузились в массив, а я уже хочу к ним обратиться.
Как узнать, что все запросы уже закончились?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У jQuery есть метод [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) для того, чтобы дождаться разрешения нескольких аякс-запросов (точнее, deferred-объектов):

```
var deferreds = [];
for (...) {
   deferreds.push($.ajax({...}));
}
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
    /* здесь код, который должен выполниться по окончанию всех аякс-запросов */
});
```

Comment: то что нужно https://gist.github.com/des1roer/617a78a20dc79ade8b4a

Answer (score 0):

Правильней использовать [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // "Fish"
    console.log( v2 ); // "Pizza"
});

d1.resolve( "Fish" );
d2.resolve( "Pizza" );
```

apply конечно работает, но могут (при таком повсеместном подходе) всплыть подводные камни, в других библиотеках, или при обновлении версии